# Struggling to push errors into array in JS

Tags: javascript, error-handling

So I'm given some code and told to update it so instead of using `console.error()` it pushes the errors into the errors array. I also need to update the code so that if there are any errors, the code throws an array of errors.

Code given:

```
function secretPasscode(code) {
  let errors = [];
  if (code.length < 14) console.error("Code is too short!");
  if (code.length > 14) console.error("Code is too long!");
  if (!code.includes("-")) console.error("Code is missing a '-'.");
  if (code !== "jWhyYFh-eTx3qt") console.error("Code is incorrect.");

  if (errors.length) {
    console.error(errors);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Would using `errors.push("Code is too short!")` be ok? What would be the best way to update it so it fulfills both requirements?

This is the test file that is used to compare it:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const solution = require("../src/solution");

describe("Solution", () => {
  describe("secretPasscode()", () => {
    it("should throw an error if the given code is too short", () => {
      const secretPasscode = () => solution("short-code");
      const msg = "Code is too short!";
      expect(secretPasscode).to.throw().with.property(0, msg);
    });
    it("should throw an error if the given code is too long", () => {
      const secretPasscode = () => solution("very-expansive-code");
      const msg = "Code is too long!";
      expect(secretPasscode).to.throw().with.property(0, msg);
    });
    it("should throw an error if the given code does not include a dash", () => {
      const secretPasscode = () => solution("codeofoklength");
      const msg = "Code is missing a '-'.";
      expect(secretPasscode).to.throw().with.property(0, msg);
    });
    it("should throw 3 errors if code is incorrect, missing dash and too short", () => {
      const secretPasscode = () => solution("shortcode");
      expect(secretPasscode).to.throw().have.lengthOf(3);
    });
    it("should throw 3 errors if code is incorrect, missing dash and too long", () => {
      const secretPasscode = () => solution("veryexpansivecode");
      expect(secretPasscode).to.throw().have.lengthOf(3);
    });
    it("should throw 2 errors if missing dash and wrong code", () => {
      const secretPasscode = () => solution("codeofoklength");
      expect(secretPasscode).to.throw().have.lengthOf(2);
    });
    it("should throw an error if the given code is simply incorrect", () => {
      const secretPasscode = () => solution("pretty-ok-code");
      const msg = "Code is incorrect.";
      expect(secretPasscode).to.throw().with.property(0, msg);
    });
    it("should return true if the code is correct", () => {
      const actual = solution("jWhyYFh-eTx3qt");
      expect(actual).to.be.true;
    });
  });
});
```

When I push the errors into the array using errors.push()

and then return the array it fails

Comment: What does your "*the code **throws** an array of errors*" actually mean?

Answer (score 2):

In order to add an error to an array its super simple!

We can use the push method on the errors object to push what we want to the array as shown below

```
errors.push("Code is too short!")
```

So for your code:

```
function secretPasscode(code) {
  let errors = [];
  if (code.length < 14) errors.push("Code is too short!");
  if (code.length > 14) errors.push("Code is too long!");
  if (!code.includes("-")) errors.push("Code is missing a '-'.");
  if (code !== "jWhyYFh-eTx3qt") errors.push("Code is incorrect.");

  if (errors.length) {
    console.error(errors);
    return false

  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, you could code it like this:

```
function secretPasscode(code) {
  const errors = [];
  if (code.length < 14) errors.push("Code is too short!");
  if (code.length > 14) errors.push("Code is too long!");
  if (!code.includes("-")) errors.push("Code is missing a '-'.");
  if (code !== "jWhyYFh-eTx3qt") errors.push("Code is incorrect.");

  if (errors.length) {
    console.error(errors);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Note that I also updated how you return from this function so that the caller can check if the code was okay.

Comment: If you actually want to "throw" the error, you could change `console.error(errors)` to `throw new Error(errors)`. This would halt execution until the error is caught.

Answer (score 1):

errors.push() should do the job,
I would suggest to make a variable for each kind of error and push that variable into array.

When you want to print a stack trace of error, you can run .map() on the array of errors and pass the error to the console.error()

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Nvm im silly.

Pushing the errors was fine as is but I simply needed to code the return as

```
throw errors
```

and everything passed!